# Space after Proof Environment to next Section

Tags: sectioning, amsmath, amsthm

I am using a modified definition of a proof environment:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
\pushQED{\qed}%
\normalfont \topsep1\p@\@plus3\p@\relax
\trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
    \scshape
#1\@addpunct{\scshape{.}}]\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
\vspace{6pt plus 3pt}
}
\makeatother
```

However, if a start a new section immediately after a proof, the spacing between the proof and the section is much smaller than in floating text. This also happens when I use the standard proof environment provided by AMS.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It should be `\addvspace`, not `\vspace`, after `\@endpefalse`.

Comment: In my experiment the space is much *bigger*.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I now switched to thmtools and this works fine!